# returning two variables from a converted string

Tags: c#

Appologies, as I'm still learning c#. I am trying to convert a string to an integer, and return both the phone and fax numbers. I was able to get the phone number to work, but am struggling to return both. Below is my attempted code:

```
string phoneFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(phone));
            string faxFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(fax));
            return string.Format("Phone: {0}, Fax: {1}", phoneFormat, faxFormat);
```

Comment: I can only return one instance... If I only choose to return the phone variable, it'll work, but it won't do both

Comment: What do you mean by instance? Generally, such method returns something like; new Contact{ Phone = phoneFormat, Fax = faxFormat }; Here, class Contact will encapsulate both properties.

Comment: If you want to return multiple things then create a class to hold multiple properties, or use a `List<string>` or a `Tuple`. Genuine suggestion though, since this is such a basic question, perhaps running through some basic C# tutorials would be a good idea for you.

Comment: I see. I get this exception:  on the string faxFormat: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: From  which  position of the input string it will be divided i.e, Split() and seperate the phone and fax number?  Based on which logic you want to seperate the string into phone and fax  @JeremieTomkins

Comment: FYI a phone number is not a numerical value, but a string consisting mostly of digits. For instance a long doesn't handle leading zeroes

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a method for this, you have 2 options for returning more than 1 value.

1. Use out parameter modifier
2. Create a data structure with 2 fields/properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuples in your method... something like:

```
(string Phone, string Fax) FormatPhoneAndFax(string phone, string fax) {
  string phoneFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(phone));
  string faxFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(fax));
  return (phoneFormat, faxFormat);
}
```

And then call it like:

```
var result = FormatPhoneAndFax(myPhone, myFax);
Console.WriteLine(result.Phone);
Console.WriteLine(result.Fax);
```

or deconstruct it, like:

```
var (phone, fax) = FormatPhoneAndFax(myPhone, myFax);
Console.WriteLine(phone);
Console.WriteLine(fax);
```

Comment: Not sure suggesting tuples is such a great idea for a beginner.

Comment: @DavidG why not? tuples are a native thing now... it may look strange for us, old farts, but precisely for begginners, they should use what is available to them natively :-)

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, this is such a basic question that any answer here isn't really useful in the long run.